# Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 4004 System.ArgumentException:

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls, esri

I am developing a esri map project on silverlight. When i add custom user control as element layer, getting that error from browser:

```
Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.ArgumentException: 
Parameter name: height
   at System.Windows.Rect..ctor(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.LayerCanvas.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

This is weird, because i didnt write any code or something. And my map service works. 
i think the problem occurs at parsing xaml files. So;

mainpage.xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="tbl.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:esri1="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
    xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:tbl"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <esri1:Map x:Name="esrimap">
            <esri1:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer Url="http://.../ArcGIS/rest/services/.../MapServer">
            </esri1:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer>

            <esri1:ElementLayer>
                <lcl:SilverlightControl1 esri1:ElementLayer.Envelope="495942.700915659,4509916.68364022,495942.700915659,4509916.683614022"></lcl:SilverlightControl1>
            </esri1:ElementLayer>

        </esri1:Map>
    </Grid>


</UserControl>
```

and silverlightcontrol.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="tbl.SilverlightControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the ESRI control's `ArrangeOverride` method.  It is attempting to create a `System.Windows.Rect` with a negative height.

The [4-argument constructor for `System.Windows.Rect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587929(v=vs.95).aspx) only throws an ArgumentException if the width and/or height are negative.  I had a quick play with this structure and can confirm this.  I can also confirm that this constructor does *not* throw an exception if the height is `NaN`, which surprised me.

Comment: Do you have more information about that or reference site maybe?

Comment: @gomp: more info about the `Rect` constructor or the ESRI control?  If it's the former, then the Remarks section of the MSDN page I linked to mentions that the constructor 'does not permit negative values for *width* and *height*'.